# Cannot access settings file

Tags: c#, .net, resources, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am creating new a project in VS2008. I copied a settings file from a different(old) project to my new project.  I am not able to access the information(some constant values) contained inside the settings file in my .cs file.

I tried restarting the application/project, still the settings file remain unaccessible in my .cs file.

Thanks,

John.

Comment: The user.config settings file that contains setting values is normally quite hard to find.  What exactly did you copy?

Comment: 1. Is the old project also VS2008, if not use the Upgrade wizard. 2. How many settings do you have? if there's less than 20 it would be faster to create a new settings file and enter the values in. 3. When you say your not able to access the info, do you mean disabled fields? disabled settings tab in Project properties? 4. Version of Visual Studio is consistent (ie your not copying from VS Pro to Express)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the namespaces in both the Settings.settings file and Settings.Designer.cs file?

It would actually be easier to create a new settings file in the new project and open a second copy of VS2008 for your old project and copy the settings between the two that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use full class path, u can read full path to the newly copied settings class file by using class view window;

The best way is still to copy old values to the new project's settings file or replace in projects settings file by link to a settings file in a both projects. making this settings file shared, if required